# Delegate control with class.cs

Tags: development, delegate-control

I searched on google for some clarifications but I didn't find the answers I've been looking for.

I want to deploy a delegate which would perform some custom functionality. That is why with a delegate I want to ship a classe with code, so I did a following:

I added a classe:

```
public class SomeClassForDelegate: WebControl
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("<p>Write some text</p>");
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

Basically this classe will write just a text. The reason why I do that is just to test if my classe is being used, normally I'll add totaly difirent functionality.

Then I have a delegate declaration in element.xml:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" ControlClass="mysolution.SomeClassForDelegate"  Sequence="90" />
</Elements>
```

Which I deploy with a feature.

Everything goes good and well but at the end I don't see the result.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update: Solved**

The problem was that the webcontrol was not put as safe control. So in an element.xml I added whole folder as a safe place. And it was working.

Thank you for input, especially Dribbel!

Comment: Are you just looking at the page, or at the page-source. The text will be inserted in the `<head>` element of the page and thus will not render in the browser.
And Did you specify a `Sequence` value in your element file?

Comment: Yep, I forgot the sequence and I added it. But still nothing :(

Comment: Did you register it as safe control? Try adding a breakpoint, what does the ULS-log say? Check if it is correctly registered with this: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/checking-which-delegate-controls-activated-site/

Comment: What Scope is the Feature?

Comment: ok with the powershell script it seems it is ok it shows in controlclass for the additionialheaderpage: the src: mysolution.SomeClassForDelegate. But why it doenst do anything then? i even write some logs from Render or OnLoad methods but nothigs come in.

Comment: Can you check if the Control is registered as safe? Build and deploy, then check your web.config file. Also check the ULS-logs for errors (an unsafe control will generate an error).

Comment: Normally I put it all the controls in the folder as safe, but I think it just can't find that control, maybe my controlclass is not refering correctly? should it be solutionname.foldername.controlname right?

Comment: Ok you were right the safe control was not fully set. In the element.xml the path of safecontrol was absolute, so i made it until folder and it was ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the following:

- Is there any warning in the ULS-logs?
- Is the `sequence` set correctly?
- Does adding a breakpoint help (this checks if the code is actually loaded)
- Check if the Control is referenced at all in the page  using http://blog.mastykarz.nl/checking-which-delegate-controls-activated-site/ ?
- Is the control registered as safe (check in the web.config after deploying)? Not safe controls will generate an error in the ULS-logs.

Comment: You were right the control was not added as safe )

Comment: @Shkipper can you share the code for your solution.